# Как открыть папку не из директории Ubuntu в программе, например в idee

Tags: linux, ubuntu

У меня Ubuntu 18
Только начал юзать.
Собственно просто в проводнике из Ubuntu могу зайти в любой диск на ПК и в том числе на тот где у меня винда и старые проекты idea.

А вот из Idea из под Ubuntu не получается. Нажимаю открыть проект и там могу перемещаться только в поле диска где у меня стоит Ubuntu.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount

Comment: Файловые менеджеры монтируют ваши разделы/диски автоматически при обращении к ним, но большая часть программ этого не делает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В unix подобных ОС любой диск может быть примонтирован к какой либо директории в файловой системе начинающейся с корня "/". Поэтому тут отсутствует понятие диск как в windows, есть понятие путь.

А по проблеме: в файловом менеджере (в вашем случае nautilus) можно нажать сочетание Ctrl+L и тогда вы увидите полный путь до директории в которой сейчас находитесь.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поискать в папках */mnt/*  и */media/<ваш логин>* - может быть там найдёте. В некоторых дистрибутвах вместо */media/<ваш логин>* будет */media/1000* или другое число больше 1000.